# Unable to retrieve sql server 2008 time(0) field values using nhibernate and c#

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, time

I successfully saved time to the time(0) field in my sql server 2008 database using c# DateTime datatype and with nhibernate. But i just unable to retrieve with the same in select query.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does "unable" mean? Do you get an error message? Can you provide the SQL query you're executing? Are you running the query directly in SSMS or are you executing it from NHibernate? What do the table structure and data look like? Etc.

Comment: Ok, the question phrasing sucks, but I have an idea what you are talking about. From memory it is not a C# DateTime type, either a TimeSpan or something like that, I cannot remember, but along those lines. Sorry I cannot be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment and this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx?PHPSESSID=lm71lj7i6gj5fjtebtb2srl4n3), use C# TimeSpan.